# What is the best way to reduce extra HTTP request for fonts in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, base64, httprequest

I am loading following styles of "Open Sans" font in my CSS.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
src: url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
src: url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot');
src: url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/oms/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: oblique;
}
// same thing for OpenSans-Light-webfont, OpenSans-LightItalic-webfont, OpenSans-Semibold-webfont, OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-webfont, OpenSans-Bold-webfont, OpenSans-BoldItalic-webfont, OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont, OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.
```

I encoded font path for all types of fonts except .eot and .ttf using base64 data URI method to reduce extra HTTP request. I did not find any solution to encode .eot and .ttf types.

[In Internet Explorer, I can clearly see it uses .eot font file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccq6G.png) (Click on link to see screen shot.)

And .ttf is used in legacy iOS, I guess (not sure).
Can any one please help me how I can do the same thing with .eot and .ttf types to reduce HTTP request? or any other solution?

Comment: you really can't without JS or OS/browser detection

Comment: why you dont use google font if you want open sans.

Comment: @DaMaxContent, thanks for the reply. but I didn't understand the last part fully "without JS or OS/browser detection". can you please elaborate?

Comment: Each font targets a specific browser and/or specific operating system for example: TTF/OTF look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf (browser support)

Comment: @mmativ, but would this avoid downloading fonts? I don't want to be fired http request for fonts.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad. While it may appear so, it does not, because as soon as google downloads its css locally, it goes off and makes more network requests to the google font servers for the additional fonts

Comment: @DaMaxContent, I tried using google font, but I can see HTTP request in Chrome debugger. Did I miss something? I simply included that code in my CSS. See the screen shot - http://i.imgur.com/LPIsPYO.png

Comment: Oh ok, so did you did not link the google font css, but embedded it in your own CSS correct?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad that was for you

Comment: @DaMaxContent, Yes, right. I copied that code in my CSS. But it's the same thing as linking google font css. Isn't it?

Comment: @DaMaxContent, In any way it will fire HTTP request for font file.

Comment: true, but it is timing. If you link the css, it will go down slower like this. Client --(request for website)--> Server --(index.html)--> client --(request for linked CSS)--> Server --(CSS file)--> client --(request for linked font (from CSS file))--> Server --(font)--> client

Comment: @RohitGaikwad as opposed to Client --(request for website)--> Server --(index.html with ***embedded*** css using the `<style>` tag)--> client --(request for linked font (from `<style>` tag))--> Server --(font)--> client